# Use pgcrypto to verify passwords generated by password_hash

Tags: php, postgresql, crypt, pgcrypto

I have password hashes stored in a Postgresql database generated with:

`password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

Now I would like to also be able to verify a user password with Postgresql and pgcrypto.

But pgcrypto's `crypt()` function is not able to verify the existing password hashes.

However - I can verify password hashes generated by Postgresql with PHP's `password_verify`.

For example:

```
password_hash('hello', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$2y$10$fD2cw7T6s4dPvk1SFHmiJeRRaegalE/Oa3zSD6.x5WncQJC9wtCAS
```

```
postgres=# SELECT crypt('hello', gen_salt('bf'));
                            crypt                             
--------------------------------------------------------------
 $2a$06$7/AGAXFSTCMu9r.08oD.UulYR0/05q7lmuCTC68Adyu/aNJkzpoIW
```

Verification:

```
// php_verify with the Postgresql hash
php > var_dump(password_verify('hello', '$2a$06$7/AGAXFSTCMu9r.08oD.UulYR0/05q7lmuCTC68Adyu/aNJkzpoIW'));
bool(true)
```

```
postgres=# SELECT crypt('hello', '$2y$10$fD2cw7T6s4dPvk1SFHmiJeRRaegalE/Oa3zSD6.x5WncQJC9wtCAS');
     crypt     
---------------
 $2JgKNLEdsV2E
(1 Zeile)
```

My questions are basically:

- Am I doing it wrong?
- If this is not possible: Is there a migration path to make this possible?

Comment: `$2y$` is a PHP specific algorithm, since its `$2a$` implementation had a bug, IIRC. The problem is probably that very few other systems support it.

Comment: This way, the password [will be logged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003333/rds-postgres-how-to-avoid-password-statement-into-log-file) in the logfile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the answer to: [Where 2x prefix are used in BCrypt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733196) which has all the gory details about the $2$ variants born from implementation bugs:

> **There is no difference between 2a, 2x, 2y, and 2b**. If you wrote your
>   implementation correctly, they all output the same result.

Based on that, one may take the hash generated by PHP's `password_hash`, replace the leading `$2y$` by `$2a$` and pass it as the second argument of pgcrypto's `crypt()`.

Using the value from your example:

```
postgres=# \set hash '$2a$10$fD2cw7T6s4dPvk1SFHmiJeRRaegalE/Oa3zSD6.x5WncQJC9wtCAS'

postgres=# SELECT crypt('hello', :'hash') = :'hash'
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks for sharing/investigating this!