# RDS Postgres - How to avoid 'password' statement into log file

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Currently, we are using 'DDL' log model for Postgres RDS. However, this log does capture the password management statement. For example, if using the statement `create user user1 with password 'some_secret_password'`, this password will be saved into a log file.

Is there any way we can avoid to save any password related information into the log? Can anyone please advise what parameter should be changed in order to not capture any password information?

Answer (score 2):

Use a different method to set the password. Neither `psql`'s `\password` nor pgAdmin's "change password" dialog have this problem.

Comment: It will still log something, just not the plain text form.  And for pgAdmin4, that is only true if you change your own password from the Object menu.  If you change your own or someone else's password through the "properties" dialog of that user, it will get logged in plain text.